# Shrinking video using requestFrameAnimation

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I'm trying to shrink a video by 50% upon key press using requestFrameAnimation. Here's what I have, but the shrinking doesn't stop once the desired size is reached.

```
function shrink_video(){

if(v.width == WIDTH * 0.5){
shrink = false;
}

var shrink_value = WIDTH * 0.001;

if(shrink){ 
v.width -= shrink_value;
}

requestAnimFrame(shrink_video);
}
```

I'm guessing I need to call cancelAnimationFrame, but I don't know how to go about doing that based on the video size. I considered using setTimeout to fire the cancel action, but that would result in inconsistent video resizing which won't work; the end size is crucial. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All numbers in javascript are floating point numbers.

This means an exact test like `v.width==WIDTH*0.50` will fail because of the excessive precision of javascript numbers.

Instead, test if v.width exceeds half WIDTH:

```
function shrink_video(){

    if(v.width>WIDTH*0.50){
        requestAnimationFrame(shrink_video);
    }

    v.width -= WIDTH*0.001;

}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. I didn't realize that precision would be an issue, so that's great to know!